# Time taken to fill the tank

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Pipe A can **drain** the tank in 5 hours while pipe B can **drain** the tank in 6 hours. If both the pipes are open then the time taken to **fill** the tank:

a) 30 hours
b) 20 hours
c) 10 hours
d) 40 hours

I am having difficulties in solving this problem. I know how long it will take pipe A and pipe B together to empty the tank but I am not sure how to do it for filling the tank. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Which pipe is emptying the tank? I'm assuming you didn't proof read this carefully :).

Comment: I'm going to guess that pipe $A$ is filling the tank while $B$ is draining the tank

Comment: I edited the post. Both A and B drain liquid from the tank

Comment: You can't fill a tank using pipes that only take water out. Perhaps there's a typo in the problem statement, wherever you found it.

Comment: If pipe A alone can _fill_ the tank in 5 hours then the problem is solvable (with reasonable assumptions; I would guess in this problem you're meant to start with an empty tank).

Answer (score 1):

HINTS: Let $V$ be the volume of the tank then

flow rate of pipe A $=\frac{V}{5}$

flow rate of pipe B $=\frac{V}{6}$

now, one should have the following cases,

1. **If both the pipes are filling the tank**
   $$\left(\frac{V}{5}+\frac{V}{6}\right)t=V$$
2. **If pipe A is filling & pipe B is draining the tank** 
   $$\left(\frac{V}{5}-\frac{V}{6}\right)t=V$$

Comment: Sorry for the confusion but both pipe A and B empty the tank. I also know that together the can do it in $30/11$ hours

Answer (score 0):

Rate of filling of pipe A, a = $1/5$ per hour

Rate of filling of pipe A, b = $1/6$ per hour

$$a*t - b*t = 1$$

$$t = 1/{(a-b)}$$

$$t = 1/{(1/5 - 1/6)}$$

$$t = 30 hours$$