# How to find the time needed to fill a reservoir when one faucet changes its condition?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The problem is as follows:

> Two faucets $A$ and $B$ together fill an empty tank in $30$ hours. If
> tap $B$ were to drain, it would take $60$ hours to fill the tank. How
> long would tap $A$ require to fill the tank when the latter is empty?

The alternatives given in my book are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&\textrm{44 hours}\\
2.&\textrm{50 hours}\\
3.&\textrm{40 hours}\\
4.&\textrm{42 hours}\\
4.&\textrm{54 hours}\\
\end{array}$

I attempted to solve this problem but I came stuck as it states that tap $B$ becomes a drain, how should this be translated as an equation?. Can someone help me with this?.

An answer which would help me the most is an algebraic approach. So far what I came up with was:

Adding speeds: Assuming the volume of the tank is $a$:

$\frac{a}{t_{1}}+\frac{a}{t_{2}}=a\frac{t_{1}+t_{2}}{t_{1}t_{2}}$

$\frac{1}{t_{1}}+\frac{1}{t_{2}}=\frac{t_{1}+t_{2}}{t_{1}t_{2}}$

$\frac{t_{1}+t_{2}}{t_{1}t_{2}}=\frac{30}{t_{1}t_{2}}$

But as mentioned, what it confuses me the most is **how** to assess the part where it mentions that faucet B is drain. **Does this means such tap will have a negative speed?** Can such thing happen?. Can someone help me with this part please?. Please try to use a step-by-step approach so I can understand. By the way, I'm aware of the existence of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1584502/time-taken-to-fill-the-tank) but it doesn't address my doubt regarding on **how to understand negative velocities** I don't understand why can arise a negative velocity?. Does this means the water is flowing in another direction or what?. Therefore I need this doubt to be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

If tap $A$ fills tank in $a$ hours and tap $B$ fills in $b$ hours individually,

then equating part of tank filled in an hour if both fill together,

$\displaystyle \frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} = \frac{1}{30}$

When $B$ becomes a drain and assuming same rate of outflow,

$\displaystyle \frac{1}{a} - \frac{1}{b} = \frac{1}{60}$

Adding both, $\displaystyle \frac{2}{a} = \frac{3}{60} \implies a = 40 \,$ hours

Comment: You got the right answer according to the official solution. But the **main question remains unanswered** what's the meaning of a negative velocity?. Does it means that the water is flowing from the inside out? or what?. Can you explain this part to me, because I find it confusing. Let's say if this probelm were about two vehicles moving in different directions, I can understand the negative sign indicates the direction. Is this *effect* the same here?. Can you *please include an explanation* for this part I'm still stuck. I noticed that you omitted the *volume* of the tank.

Comment: Is it because you took out the volume and did not considered as part of the fractions have you used?. Can you attend this doubt also as well please?.

Comment: Yes the question is a bit confusing and not worded clearly. It says $B$ becomes the drain which means instead of water flowing in from $B$, it is flowing out in the second case. The velocity of the drain is not given so it was logical for me to assume the velocity magnitude remained the same - it just turned from inflow (plus) to outflow(minus).

Answer (score 0):

The phrasing is peculiar. "If tap B were to drain, it would take 60 hours to fill the tank."  Normally "draining" **empties** a tank!

I am going to interpret this as saying "Two faucets A and B together fill an empty tank in 30 hours. If tap B only were used, it would take 60 hours to fill the tank."

So tap B fills at the rate of 1 tank per 60 hours or 1/60 "tank per hours".  Call the number of hours it would take to fill the tank with faucet A only "x".  With A and B both working, it would take 1/x+ 1/60= 1/30.    Multiply both sides by 60x: 60+ x= 2x so A= 60.  It would take 60 hours using A  only.

Another way of looking at this is that B alone could fill half the tank in the 30 hours so A has to fill the other half in those same 30 hours so A is filling at the same speed as B.

Comment: Also the confusing use of the word "latter" in the problem, almost makes it more of an English test than an algebra word problem.

Comment: @user247327 The official solution according to my book is $40$ hours. It seems the intended approach was to *assume* in a hypothetical situation if the tap $B$ is draining the tank and tap $A$ is filling the tank, the tank would still be filled but it would take $60$ hours to do so. Hence the solution would *imply* a negative velocity for tap $B$, thus **the main question remains unattended** **why is there a negative velocity** what is the physical equivalent or meaning in the real world, is it that the water is flowing from the inside out?. Can you **explain this part please?**